# multiple aggregation with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like:

```
{
  "src": "value",
  "dst": "value",
  "subject": "value"
}
```

My first goal is aggregating them by `src` and `dst` fields and get the `subject`s that are tied to the tuple (`src`, `dst`). Here is my query:

```
db.mycollection.aggreate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
    "src": "$src",
    "dst": "$dst"
      },
      "subjects": {
      "$push": "$subject"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Thanks to this query, I get every `subject` per both `src` and `dst`. Here is an expected result:

```
[
  {
    "src": "distinct src",
    "dst": "distinct dst",
    "subjects": [
      {
    "distinct subject",
    "distinct subject",
    "distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject"
    "another distinct subject"
      ]
  },
  {
    "src": "another distinct src",
    "dst": "another distinct dst",
    "subjects": [
    "distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject",
    "another distinct subject"
      ]
  }
]
```

The next step is: how could I group these `subject` so I could have a field that counts these subjects? I mean, I would like to get a result like:

```
[
  {
    "src": "distinct src",
    "dst": "distinct dst",
    "subjects": [
      {
    "subject": "distinct subject",
    "count": 3
      },
      {
    "subject": "another distinct subject",
    "count": 5
      }
  },
  {
    "src": "another distinct src",
    "dst": "another distinct dst",
    "subjects": [
      {
    "subject": "distinct subject",
    "count": 1
      },
      {
    "subject": "another distinct subject",
    "count": 11
      }
  }
]
```

I don't know whether that is possible or not since I'm pretty new to mongodb ; if anyone has any clue though, I'd very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the final result, I think you should count for each **subject** firstly. Below for your reference:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            src : "$src",
            dst : "$dst",
            subject : "$subject"
        },
        count : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            src : "$_id.src",
            dst : "$_id.dst"
        },
        subjects : {
            $push : {
                subject : "$_id.subject",
                count : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        src : "$_id.src",
        dst : "$_id.dst",
        subjects : "$subjects"
    }
}]);
```